# Cleaner way to unpack nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am receiving data in batches from an API in JSON format. I wish to store only the values, in a list.

The raw data looks like this **and will always look like this, i.e: all {...} will look like the first example**:

```
data = content.get('data')
>>> [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}, {...}, {...}, ...]
```

The nested dictionary is making this harder; I need this unpacked as well.

Here is what I have, which works but it feels so bad:

```
unpacked = []
data = content.get('data')
for d in data:
    item = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == 'b':
            for val in v.values():
                item.append(val)
        else:
            item.append(v)
    unpacked.append(item)
```

Output:

```
>>> [[1,2,3,4], [...], [...], ...]
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: Can you provide the desired output as well

Comment: Done. Let me know if it needs clarification.

Comment: If you are sure that this is the same pattern for all the elements in the list but with different keys, you can replace `k == 'b'` with `type(v) ==  dict`

Comment: Your code does not work. For `data = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}, {'f':5,'g':6}]`, it gives `[[1, 'c', 'd', 4], [5, 6]]`

Comment: @anupsabraham Prefer `isinstance(v, dict)`. A simple recursive function with two branch base on `isinstance(v, dict)` extending with sublist or just appending current element should work.

Comment: Can the dictionaries also contain lists _inside_ them?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, no, the format I have supplied is the only possible data input.

Comment: @KaushikNP thanks, fixed it - was a typo

Comment: For `[{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}, {'f':5,'g':6}]`, should the result be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` or `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]`?

Comment: This operation isn't safe, since Python (currently) doesn't guarantee the order of dict items (although in Python 3.6 insertion order is preserved, but that's currently an implementation order that shouldn't be relied on). So to do this safely, you need some way to ensure that the keys are always unpacked in the correct order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a recursive function and some type tests:

```
data = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}, {'f':5,'g':6}]

def extract_nested_values(it):
    if isinstance(it, list):
        for sub_it in it:
            yield from extract_nested_values(sub_it)
    elif isinstance(it, dict):
        for value in it.values():
            yield from extract_nested_values(value)
    else:
        yield it

print(list(extract_nested_values(data)))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that it outputs a flat generator, not a list of lists.

Comment: Won't work for `data = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}, {'f':5,'g':6}]`. Will give `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: You should consider using `isinstance` instead of `type(...) == ...`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Thanks. Updated

Comment: Quick nitpick: For your sample input, it should give `[[2, 3, 1, 4], [5, 6]]` a nested list, not a flat one. (btw, gave you a +1)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and KaushikNP: I wrote this as a feature. You're right though, it's possibly a bug ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dictionaries do not contain inner lists, you could define a simple routine to unpack a nested dictionary, and iterate through each item in data using a loop.

```
def unpack(data):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from unpack(v)
        else:
            yield v
```

Note that this function is as simple as it is thanks to the magic of `yield from`. Now, let's call it with some data.

```
data = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}, {'f':5,'g':6}]  # Data "borrowed" from Kaushik NP
result = [list(unpack(x)) for x in data]

print(result)
[[2, 3, 1, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Note the lack of order in your result, because of the arbitrary order of dictionaries.

Comment: something does not look quite right here. Did you try it?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yup, ran this on IPython. Copy paste error perhaps?

Comment: `for x in data` makes `x = 'a'` in the first iteration which is then passed to `unpack` as `data`. Then you do `'a'.items()` which would raise an error.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yup, definitely a copy paste error ;-) (pasted the wrong sample data)

Comment: One problem with this approach: it doesn't preserve the order of items (unless you use Python 3.6 or better).

Comment: happens to the best of you it seems

Comment: @PM2Ring I could argue that that's the dictionary's fault, :-) but I agree with you on that.

Comment: @PM2Ring I guess that could be solved by using `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I will; I am still doing some testing with various techniques.

Comment: @Petar Sure, let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, based on the excellent answer of Eric Duminil, here is a function that returns the maximum depth of a nested dict or list:

```
def depth(it, count=0):
    """Depth of a nested dict.
    # Arguments
        it: a nested dict or list.
        count: a constant value used in internal calculations.
    # Returns
        Numeric value.
    """
    if isinstance(it, list):
        if any(isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict) for v in it):
            for v in it:
                if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict):
                    return depth(v, count + 1)
        else:
            return count
    elif isinstance(it, dict):
        if any(isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict) for v in it.values()):
            for v in it.values():
                if isinstance(v, list) or isinstance(v, dict):
                    return depth(v, count + 1)
        else:
            return count
    else:
        return count
```

In the Python tradition, it is zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Doing recursively :

```
def traverse(d): 
    for key,val in d.items(): 
        if isinstance(val, dict): 
             traverse(val) 
        else: 
             l.append(val) 

out=[]
for d in data:
    l=[]
    traverse(d)
    out.append(l)

print(out)
```

#driver values :

```
IN : data = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}, {'f':5,'g':6}]
OUT : out = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

**EDIT :** A better way to do this is using `yield` so as not to have to rely on global variables as in the first method.

```
def traverse(d): 
    for key,val in d.items(): 
        if isinstance(val, dict): 
             yield from traverse(val) 
        else: 
             yield val

out = [list(traverse(d)) for d in data]
```

Comment: Are you using a global function? I'd recommend against doing that.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I didn't want to either. Though works out with `append`. But couldn't figure out against how to create sublists otherwise.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ,  I guess `yield` helps there. Will have to look into it. Don't have much experience using it.

Comment: Yup, `yield` really is the only way to do this without using global or mutable arguments.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , yeah, should look into it

Answer (score 0):

Other answers (especially @COLDSPEED's) have already covered the situation, but here is a slightly different code based on the old adage *it's better to ask forgiveness than permission* , which I tend to prefer to type checking:

```
def unpack(data):
    try:
        for value in data.values():
            yield from unpack(value)
    except AttributeError:
        yield data


data = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}, 'e':4}]
unpacked = [list(unpack(item)) for item in data]
```