# map list based on dict internal values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list like:

```
[{'sample': {'sample_context': {'board': u'9', 'encoder': u'1'}, 18421: u'1191'}}, {'sample': {'sample_context': {'board': u'5', 'encoder': u'1'}, 18422: u'2251'}}, {'sample': {'sample_context': {'board': u'9', 'encoder': u'1'}, 18423: u'2291'}}, {'sample': {25680: u'3321', 'sample_context': {'board': u'2', 'encoder': u'1'}}}, {'sample': {'sample_context': {'board': u'9', 'encoder': u'1'}, 29100: u'5591'}}]
```

How could I separate values i.e. `18421: u'1191', 18422: u'2251'` etc based per `sample_context` field

I tried to do but it doesn't work, I think I need to map values based on sample_context field

```
[sample_sent['sample'] for sample_sent in x]
```

The goal is to answer give me all the values with context lets say: `{'board': u'9', 'encoder': u'1'}`

Comment: Looks like this one was already answered previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845464/cleaner-way-to-unpack-nested-dictionaries

Comment: No, Updated question

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following comprehension will extract such a mapping:

```
{k:v for d in lst for d2 in d.values() for k,v in d2.items() if isinstance(k,int)}
# {18421: '1191', 18422: '2251', 18423: '2291', 25680: '3321', 29100: '5591'}
```

Comment: But I need to know which value belongs to which contexts. Basically I need to map values based on contexts.

Comment: Then pls show the exact data structure you would want for your sample input.

Comment: Ah, you mean like collect the kv pairs for lets say context "b9e1" which occurs more than once?

Comment: Yes, list of values per sample_context. So I could ask give me all the values with context lets say:  {'board': u'9', 'encoder': u'1'}